# Existe diferença entre services, plugins e modulos dentro de uma estrutura de framework mvc?

Tags: php, mvc, framework

Estou estudando a estrutura mvc e estou tentando ver alguns exemplos de como estruturar alguns projetos e me surgiu algumas duvidas.

Vi que em algumas estruturas, eles colocam classes com auth, router, template na pasta services!

Em outras colocam na pasta modules ou plugins!

Bem, minha duvida é se exite alguma diferença entre plugins, services e modulos dentro da estrutura de um framework mvc?

Desde já, agradeço muito pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Services é algo relacionado a serviços da sua aplicação como por exemplo: Gerar um boleto bancário, gerar um documento pdf etc...

Plugins são serviços também, mas são serviço de terceiros algo já pronto que você pegou de algum lugar.

E módulos, é para você modular o seu projeto. Por exemplo, em seu projeto pode ter o modulo Financeiro, Clientes, Produtos, Usuários e por ai vai.

Espero ter ajudado 
Saudações,